Read/write stdin/stdout of a WASI module in Node
Node's experimental WASI interface seems to support stdin & stdout, however instead of returning some kind of streams (WritableStream / ReadableStream seem like the obvious choice), you have to pass in some file descriptors:

This seems like a very odd design. Maybe it's temporary. In any case, how can I adapt this interface so that I can use WriteableStream / ReadableStream instead? (That's what the thing I am connecting the WASI module to expects.)
